# OpenLayers 3 select style

Tags: openlayers-3

In OL2 I was able to specify a "select" style in the style definition. In OL3 this doesn't seem to exist. If I understand it correctly, I can set a style for the select interaction. However, this likely won't work in my case since every layer has a unique "selected" style. Am I mistaken in my assessment of the capability? Is there another/optimal way to do this in OL3?

Comment: Are you able to store some parameter in each feature?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have a style parameter stored in each `ol.Feature`, you can add a [`ol.style.StyleFunction`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.style.html#.StyleFunction) to your [`ol.interaction.Select`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html) and return a style based on this parameter. Like so:

```js
var styles = {
  'route': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8]
    })
  }),
  'icon': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      src: 'pin.png'
    })
  }),
  'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      snapToPixel: false,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2
      })
    })
  })
};

var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return [styles[feature.get('style_parameter')]];
  }
});
```

And your feature would be like:

```js
var geoMarker = new ol.Feature({
  style_parameter: 'geoMarker',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0,0])
});
```

Comment: Is there a more practical way in scenarios where one would have hundreds of styles for thousands of features in many (50+) layers? Ideally, I need to set the style on an existing select interaction. If I set the style in the on select event the style doesn't get applied.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a very old thread, but since I haven't been able to find a clear solution to this particular problem yet, I still deem it fit to post mine. Not sure how it holds up with a large number of layers and features, but this is the most elegant and concise solution I could come up with.
BTW: I'm using the latest version of OpenLayers, which at the moment is 6.3.1.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    ...
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            ...
            // Default style for layer1
            style: default1,
            // Hover style for layer1 (custom property)
            hoverStyle: hover1,
            // Selected style for layer1 (custom property)
            selectedStyle: selected1
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            ...
            // Default style for layer2
            style: default2,
            // Hover style for layer2 (custom property)
            hoverStyle: hover2,
            // Selected style for layer2 (custom property)
            selectedStyle: selected2
        })
    ],
    ...
});

var hoverInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
    style: function(feature) {
        var layer = hoverInteraction.getLayer(feature);
        return layer.values_.hoverStyle;
    }
});
map.addInteraction(hoverInteraction);

var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    style: function(feature) {
        var layer = selectInteraction.getLayer(feature);
        return layer.values_.selectedStyle;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve with this piece of code so people can better help you.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve, I actually achieved. With 'my solution' I meant just that: a way to solve OP's problem that seems to work. In OpenLayers 6.3.1 that is.
I just felt I had to share this, since finding examples on styling for hovered over and selected features is quite hard to find.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion caused by my comments. This occurred in the review queue and I thought it was a question instead of an answer, thus the comment. Thanks for contributing!