# Select interaction style not used when feature has its own style

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

My question follows on this question:
[OpenLayers 3 select style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588014/openlayers-3-select-style)

When a feature has its own style (rather than using its layer's style) the ol.interaction.Select "style" property is not used, or if the "style" property is a function, the function is not called.

This http://jsfiddle.net/y13xLmx6/13/ is the same as the jfiddle provided in the answer to the [OpenLayers 3 select style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588014/openlayers-3-select-style) question but with the addition of a style being applied to the line feature:

```
featureLine.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.8)', 
    width: 8
  })
}))
```

When the line feature is selected the yellow select interaction style is not applied, nor is the `console.log()` statement executed.The featurePoint, which does not have a style assigned to it, does get the interaction style and the `console.log()` statement is executed.

So how do you apply the interaction style to a feature that has its own style defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why select interaction doesn't log when line is selected but you can set a different style on `select` event:

```
select.on('select', function(evt){
  evt.selected.forEach(function(each) {
    each.setStyle(styles[each.get('type')]);
  });
  evt.deselected.forEach(function(each) {
    each.setStyle(null); // more likely you want to restore the original style
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. So in summary is it correct to say that the "style" property of a select interaction is used only when features are styled by layer, and that when features are styled individually then their selected/deselected style must be coded within the .on('select') event handler? That seems to be what I'm seeing but it isn't intuitive to me.

Comment: Well it seems it's need some more tests to confirm this behavior.